# submitting form on through <a> with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I am submitting the form with the help of the below code.

```
    <form name="advanceSalaryUpdate" method="POST" action="MainController" id="advanceSalaryUpdate">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateAdvanceSalaryDetail">
        <input type="hidden" name="salID" value="15">
        <a href="javascript:document.advanceSalaryUpdate.submit()">15</a>
    </form>
```

But it's gives error  "Uncaught TypeError: document.advanceSalaryUpdate.submit is not a function".

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: **Use a submit button!**. A link that doesn't have a real URL but executes some JavaScript to pretend to be a submit button is over-complicated, fragile, bloated, and a terrible idea.

Comment: Why not use a submit button?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will use submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `onclick` event on the anchor text to trigger the click event on the Submit link.

But

I suggest to use the `submit button` to submit the form.

```
<form name="advanceSalaryUpdate" method="POST" action="MainController" id="advanceSalaryUpdate">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateAdvanceSalaryDetail">
    <input type="hidden" name="salID" value="15">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('advanceSalaryUpdate').submit();">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Actually, I have now used submit button as per suggestion and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 $("#advanceSalaryUpdate").submit()
```

or

```
document.getElementById("#advanceSalaryUpdate").submit()
```

instead of href try using javascript onclick function

in case you wish to submit by make use of name attribute  use

```
$("[name=advanceSalaryUpdate]").submit()
```